# LOCK TABLES does not work as expected with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb, locking

I try to understand why there is an error in the following case stating that a table was "not locked" even though a `(WRITE) LOCK` was issued just before.

This is the setup (MySQL / MariaDB):

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    id INT
);

CREATE TABLE B
(
    id INT
);
```

Here are the cases (first one being the failing one):

```
# does not work --> Error: "Table 'B' was not locked with LOCK TABLES" on 2nd statement
LOCK TABLES A WRITE, B WRITE;
INSERT INTO A (id) VALUES ((SELECT 1 FROM B)), ((SELECT 2 FROM B));
UNLOCK TABLES;

# works (single statements)
LOCK TABLES A WRITE, B WRITE;
INSERT INTO A (id) VALUES ((SELECT 1 FROM B));
INSERT INTO A (id) VALUES ((SELECT 2 FROM B));
UNLOCK TABLES;

# works (table aliases)
LOCK TABLES A WRITE, B tb1 WRITE, B tb2 WRITE;
INSERT INTO A (id) VALUES ((SELECT 1 FROM B tb1)), ((SELECT 2 FROM B tb2));
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

What causes the error in the first case?

---

Edit: I simplified the example again to the bare minimum.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle-MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c11027b3bc138b0358d04aeb9dce1b97) and [dbfiddle-MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=c11027b3bc138b0358d04aeb9dce1b97).

Comment: @wchiquito Your fiddle just does not display the error. If you put a select behind the statement in question, you'll see it won't be executed.

Comment: But looking at the exampels in the docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html / section 'Table Lock Acquisition') it seems to be a limitation. Although a very strage one to me.

Comment: Indeed, what you mentioned is correct, using [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d4bESgeJACXgFM7a8wBAbu/0) the error is thrown. The following is indicated in the documentation [13.3.6 LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES Statements :: Table Lock Acquisition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html#table-lock-acquisition): `You cannot refer to a locked table multiple times in a single query using the same name.`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant in my last comment. :-)

Comment: If you are using InnoDB, don't use `LOCK TABLES`; use transactions instead.